# Rails 3, compass not working with @mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, mixins

I have two .scss documents with the following sample code:

tables.scss:

```
@mixin ftable {
    table {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
}
```

page.scss:

```
#projects-listing {
    @include ftable;
}
```

They are required in this order from application.scss:

```
 *= require ./tables
 *= require_tree ./partials
```

where the partials directory contains my page.scss file.

When I load the page, i'm getting an undefined mixin ftable exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Sass mixins (including compass) you need to use the sass `@import` function rather than the manifest style `require` function.

Try this instead in `application.css.scss`:

```
@import 'tables'
@import 'page'
@import 'any other files you have'
```

Order is important - those files with mixins need to be imported first before the files which would use the mixin.

Comment: thank you. Your suggestion works fine! It would be nice to import a whole directory with @import statement of sass...